# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_openid' (for Python3.6)

Tags: flask, openid, python-3.6

I was trying to run a Flask project using Python 3.6.

I encountered an error:

...

from flask_openid import OpenID
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_openid'

Flask-OpenID is available in my Python v3.5 dist-packages.

(When I run:
"sudo pip3 install Flask-OpenID", it shows 
"Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Flask-OpenID in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages" )

What should I do to install openid for Python 3.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me,

```
python3.6 -m pip install flask_openid
```

solved the issue.

The above command will install openid for python3.6.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-OpenID/#how-to-use) states that you should import `OpenID` as follows:

```
from flask.ext.openid import OpenID
```

The package itself is installed correctly (in your Python3.5 environment), as shown by `pip` when you try to install it again:

> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Flask-OpenID in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages

However, as you state the in your question:

> I was trying to run a Flask project using **Python 3.6**

You might want to make sure your `python3` and `pip3` are actually pointing to where you want them to, e.g. on your terminal:

```
$ ls -l $(which pip3)
```

Or even better, you should really look into creating [virtualenvs](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) for your projects, it helps a lot avoiding these kinds of problems in the first place:

- create a new Python 3.6 virtualenv
- activate your new virtualenv
- install your requirements with pip inside the virtualenv

Then run your script in this virtualenv, and you'll be sure you are using exactly the Python you want, and your dependencies are where you expect them to be (and only there, not somewhere else messing up other projects).

Now this might look like a lot of effort, but it takes no more than a couple minutes the first time you do it, will quickly become second nature, and save you a ton of headache down the road.

Comment: flask.ext is deprecated. That's why I went for flask_openid.

Comment: For me, python is pointing to python3.6; but, python3 to python3.5. As you pointed out, that should be the issue.